# Databinding: conditional onclick call

Tags: android, data-binding, android-xml, android-databinding

From my layout, when a user tap a view i need to call different method based on a boolean value passed to layout.

i've something like:

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.example.MyObject" />

        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.MyViewModel" />

        <variable
            name="aBolean"
            type="Boolean" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:onClick="@{()-> aBoolean ? viewmodel.methodOne() : viewmodel.methodTwo()}"
      />

</layout>
```

but when i build my code, i obtain an error:

```
error: variable aBolean is already defined in method _internalCallbackOnClick(int,View)
```

how can i do?

Comment: can you add your ```viwemodel``` class? because this is working for me. this bug will fix for you by rename ```aBoolean```

Comment: I have checked your code and it's working fine. Your only mistake is "aBoolean" spelling mistake in xml file. It should be "aBolean"

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
android:onClick="@{()-> type.equals(`hello) ? adapter1.editClick(position) :adapter.editClick(position)}"
```